# Get value of HREF for links within a certain Class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, href, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to process a page to find the value of href's within a certain div class. Please bear in mind I'm not using the class of the `<a>`.

Here is what I have:

```
var domains = document.getElementsByClassName('r');
for(var i = 0; i < domains.length; i++){
var hello = document.getElementsByClassName('r')[i].innerHTML;
alert(hello);
}
```

This works fine and will "alert" the content within the class. (I know this isn't well supported in IE but that's fine).

I get an alert like:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887307/getting-href-value-of-from-a-tag"    onmousedown="return     rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNGsxCA6nMXughTW44nSEa94KtbEaQ','','0CC8QFjAA','','',event)">    <em>javascript</em> - <em>getting href</em> value of from &lt;a&gt; tag - Stack Overflow</a>
```

What's the best way to get the value within the href?

The HTML is like this:

```
<h3 class="r"><a onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNFgNBuo2EfLPoNBi3hGgbuTeLwODw','','0CC8QFjAA','','',event)" href="http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fprop_html_innerhtml.asp&ei=LacjUo4lw9m0BpLVgYAK&usg=AFQjCNFgNBuo2EfLPoNBi3hGgbuTeLwODw&bvm=bv.51495398,d.Yms"> … </a></h3>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.attributes) instead of [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML). With your HTML you also need to use an inner loop to get `<a>` children of `.r` elements:

```
var domains = document.getElementsByClassName('r');
for(var i = 0; i < domains.length; i++){
    var anchors = domains.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var j = 0; j < anchors.length; j++) {
        alert(anchors[j].attributes.href);
    }
}
```

or you could switch to [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll) for a nicer querying API:

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.r > a');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    alert(anchors[i].attributes.href);
}
```

Note that I reused the `domains` variable since there's no reason to keep re-querying the DOM at every loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice, following of Sanja's snippet I used: `var domains = document.getElementsByClassName('r');
for (var i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
  var links = domains[i].getElementsByTagName('A');
    alert(links[0].attributes['href'].value);
}` to show the domains for multiple classes with single hrefs. Thanks

Comment: Since you said you're not especially concerned with compatibility, `document.querySelectorAll()` would really clean up this code.

Comment: The second code block works very nicely for what I needed on this project.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (http://jsfiddle.net/JMsYk/):

```
var domains = document.getElementsByClassName('r');
for (var i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
  var links = domains[i].getElementsByTagName('A');
  for (var j in links) {
    alert(links[j].attributes['href'].value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Using:`var domains = document.getElementsByClassName('r');
for (var i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
  var links = domains[i].getElementsByTagName('A');
  for (var j in links) {
    alert(links[j].attributes['href']);
  }
}` gives me one alert saying: [object Attr]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but you could do something like this:

```
var domains = document.getElementsByClassName('r');
for(var i = 0; i < domains.length; i++){
  var hello = domains[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
  //Just in case there's more than one anchor inside a div
  for (j = 0; j < hello.length; j++) {
    // do anything with hello[j].attributes.href (the href of each anchor)
    alert(hello[j].attributes.href);
  }
  //If you just have an anchor inside each h3 then simply
  alert(hello.attributes.href);
}
```

domains already returns a list with all the h3 with class 'r' so inside the loop you can access each div as domains[i], then you get a list with all anchors inside the current h3, then loop through them (in case there's more than one inside a div), and alert the href of each anchor

Answer (score 0):

For that, you wrap links into a class as like-

```
<li class="list-values">
  <a href="/getting-href-value">Getting Href Value</a>
</li>
<li class="list-values">
  <a href="/other-link">Other Link</a>
</li>
```

and perform javascript-

```
document.querySelector("li.list-values > a[href='/getting-href-value']");
```

note that I used 'querySelector()' to select one value. You also use querySelectorAll() with the same query to select all.